# ERROR 1130 (HY000) or ERROR 2003 (HY000) : connect mysql from windows to ubuntu on VMware

Tags: mysql, linux

I tried many ways but failed.I want to connect the MySQL on Linux in VMware from Windows.

- VMware:11.1.0 build-2496824
- Linux:Ubuntu 14.10
- Windows:win 8.1 x64
- MySQL Version

  - windws: 5.6.24
  - Linux: 5.5.43
- IP

  - Windows:192.168.1.102
  - Linux: 192.168.1.100

PS: Ping requests receive packets from each other.

When I input the cmd:

```
mysql -h 192.168.1.100 -u root_test -p
```

i am sure i input the right pwd,but the mysql server returns "ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '192.168.1.100' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL Server"
or "ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.100' (10061)".

```
Proto   Recv-Q   Send-Q   Local Address      Foreign Address       State       PID/Program name
tcp          0        0   0.0.0.0:3306       0.0.0.0:*             LISTEN        -    



my.cnf:bind-address = 0.0.0.0

service iptables status
iptables: unrecognized service

select user,host from user;
+------------------+---------------+
| user             | host          |
+------------------+---------------+
| root             | 127.0.0.1     |
| root_test        | 192.168.1.102 |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost     |
| root             | localhost     |
+------------------+---------------+

show grants for 'root_test'@'192.168.1.102';

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root_test@192.168.1.102                                                                                            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root_test'@'192.168.1.102' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'MD5-PWD'                                   |

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

### Update

I finally figured it out by changing the IPv4 properties `Obtain an IP address automatically` to `use the following IP address` on windows.

[image: here]

PS:VMware's internet setting is `Bridged`.

thank @s3v3n and @Drew Pierce very much,you are kind and friendly. thank you.

Comment: Did you run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`?

Comment: yes,i did. but it shows `0 rows affected` :(

Comment: Try granting to wildcard host:
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root_test'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: By the way, when trying to connect using the command-line, did you specify the host to connect to? Like this:
`mysql -u root_test -p -h 192.168.1.100`

Comment: You're trying to connect from the Windows box to the MySQL server on the Linux box, right?

Comment: Your error says that the host `192.168.1.100` is not allowed to connect but the user is created for the `192.168.1.102`.

Comment: yes,i used cmd `mysql -h 192.168.1.100 -u root_test -p`,i am tyring connect from windows to MySQL on VMware

Comment: Can you please check that the error is the one you posted? It really seems odd that the IP in the error is `192.168.1.100`.

Comment: yes,it did.i think it is the unfriendly error msg of MySQL.

Comment: `mysql -h 192.168.1.100 -u root_test -p` - you're running it on windows or on linux?

Comment: i did this on windows

Comment: Since your windows machine has the IP `192.168.1.102` you should get a different error. Here's an example of the error I get when I'm connecting from my home network to a remote server: http://i.imgur.com/Ze3ZJ1S.png

Comment: In any case, allowing the user to connect from any host `%` should solve your issue

Comment: i tried '%',but it didn't work.i'll do again tomorrow,thx for ur answer.

Comment: i tried again.it didn't work neither.before i tried and after i tried,the error became `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.100' (10061)`.

Comment: This is a different error. Perhaps you are trying to connect to the wrong IP.

Comment: i ran cmd `ifconfig` and saw eth0 inet is `192.168.1.100`...

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) change my.conf (whatever your mysql conf file is called). And set bind-address to 0.0.0.0 as it is prob 127.0.0.1

2) stop/restart mysql daemon

`Connections now are not limited to those from localhost. The default is localhost for obvious security reason until dev guy tweaks it`

3) grants with flush

4) firewall

Good luck!

---

**Edit**:

shows info necessary in some environments to set up user / get in

> mainly it shows how sqlyog can clue you into your hostname as seen or
>   known by the mysql daemon (regardless of what you think your IP
>   address is).

so I am sitting here thinking my external ip address on my workstation is 188.188.188.188 and I plow forward with that in my servers create user and grants and it doesn't work ultimately to get in to mysql.

I am also looking for tight security.

create an instance on aws ec-2 or your vm environment.

mine is created with public dns = ec2-23-21-7-136.compute-1.amazonaws.com

only port 22 open (ssh)

mysql is baked-in and running, blind to outside world.

run sqlyog to get in. it bombs. good. visible [here](http://i.imgur.com/y5SBHeW.gif)

---

ssh/putty into or sit at server (mine is in Singapore, not sitting at)
at linux prompt i get into mysql

so now i am at a mysql prompt (not OS, i know u know this someone else might not :>)

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
+------------------+------------------------+
| user             | host                   |
+------------------+------------------------+
| root             | 127.0.0.1              |
| foo_user         | w.x.y.z                |
+------------------+------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

go into vm and open port 3306 for inbound 0.0.0.0/0  (anywhere)

---

try sqlyog connect again for root.

bombs. good. the bomb gave us good info.

visible [here](http://i.imgur.com/bpR8ipN.gif)

i know who mysql thinks i should be, glad root can't get in

'root'@'xxxx.yyyy.comcastbusiness.net'

---

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| foo                |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| phpmyadmin         |
| test               |
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

so with that i create user

```
CREATE USER 'fred7'@'xxxx.yyyy.comcastbusiness.net' IDENTIFIED BY 'bonehead7';
```

and

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'fred7'@'xxxx.yyyy.comcastbusiness.net';
```

---

for those of you crazy about wildcards, make your security less tight

---

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
+------------------+-------------------------------+
| user             | host                          |
+------------------+-------------------------------+
| root             | 127.0.0.1                     |
| foo_user         | w.x.y.z                       |
| fred7            | xxxx.yyyy.comcastbusiness.net |
+------------------+-------------------------------+
```

---

try sqlyog connect again, this time for user=fred7 password=bonehead7
good.

i am in.

visible [here](http://i.imgur.com/OLJQyeI.gif)

---

and there was much rejoicing (at least for me)

Comment: i tried but failed,about firewall is "iptables: unrecognized service"

Comment: Do 1 and 2. Then retest. 3 and 4 are things to consider not actual commands to type

Comment: Also sometimes VMs like vmware on same box are on a different subnet. You have 3 ip addresses/subnets to figure out. Document the ip/sub from a prompt running inside vmware

Comment: i have set the `set bind-address to 0.0.0.0` and  `service mysql restart`.but it doesn't work.the same error msg.`ERROR 11130...`

Comment: And what exactly is 'ServerIP' document that in question. It is important

Comment: The bind address was done in the file overwriting localhost or 127.0.0.1 entry?

Comment: Sounds like you `set bind-address` at a command prompt which is wrong

Comment: ServerIP is 192.168.1.100,which is the VM's IP,and i have changed the bind-address in the file my.cnf,the conf of MySQL.sry for my express,`set bind-address to 0.0.0.0` doesn't mean a cmd prompt,it means it is an opeation .and when connect the mysql server,it returns error msg,i think they are in the same subnet...

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a firewall/subnet issue because the error says that the host is not allowed to connect from that IP not that the connection failed.

Comment: I am with you on that. I always use a program like Mysql workbench to try a connect. It will tell u failed message with more info About what mysql sees you as

Comment: It is THAT info that is important for add user and grants

Comment: bad luck.i try to connect by using SQLYog and by a command prompt,the same error.i hate the number of 1130...

Comment: We are expecting it to fail but using debug info from it to solve larger problem

Comment: e...it seems there is only a message box,showing the error msg of 1130.no logs for us to debug

Comment: edit performed on answer `after step 4` showing image links

Comment: i ran cmd `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root_test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root_test';` and then `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` and `service mysql restart`.the error is `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.100' (10061)`.

Comment: Great. But how is that relevant to you performing the steps like i did showing images meticulously after each documented step

Comment: i performed all the steps,in fact,i did all these before i asked the question.and i tried again just now.what let me down is `ERROR 2003...` and `ERROR 1130...`.thx for your help.i think your answer will help others much.Orz,so tired...